# Script/Batch file to add HKCU key

Tags: registry, batch-file

We have an application which creates an HKCU entry when first run by each user. As the registry is locked down, this causes an error and requires our Tech Support to grant then remove access each time. We have 300 users and can rollout the application's installation remotely via a LANDesk batch file package. I need to be able to add something to the batch file which will pre-install the key for all users. Does anyone know if this is possible and how I might go about it?

Answer (score 1):

use [reg.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/reg.mspx?mfr=true)

It's available on Windows from XP onwards.

Comment: Thanks Polemon. looks good for amending the registry. 
Can you help me with how I use it to amend all existing HCKU keys and default for new ones?

Comment: With *all* HKCU keys, do you mean all in the /HKCU/ directory? That would be many, to say the least!